# Python SqlAlchemy: Data are inserted with NULL values instead of specified values

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have made the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
# -*- Mode: python; c-basic-offset: 4 -*-

from sqlalchemy import *

db=create_engine('postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1/hello')
db.echo = False
metadata = MetaData(db)

people=Table('people',metadata)

# Insert Data
stmt=people.insert()
stmt.execute(name="Dimitrios",surname="Desyllas")
stmt.execute({'name':"Dionysis",'surname':"Arsenis"})

#Select Data
stmt=people.select()
results=stmt.execute().fetchone()

for result in results:
    print "Result:"
    print result
```

Using the following postgresql table:

```
hello=# \d people
                                 Table "public.people"
 Column  |         Type          |                      Modifiers                      
---------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer               | not null default nextval('people_id_seq'::regclass)
 name    | character varying(60) | 
 surname | character varying(60) |
```

(Dump from psql)

When I run the script I get No result output from the and when I manually select the query `SELECT * FROM people` Ι get the following results:

```
hello=# SELECT * FROM people;
 id | name | surname 
----+------+---------
 19 |      | 
 20 |      | 
(2 rows)
```

And I wonder why the `name` and `surname` columns have no values. The script was based on: http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `autoload=True` the table by replacing the line:

```
people=Table('people',metadata)
```

With:

```
people=Table('people',metadata,autoload=True)
```